# Dropdown not Updating lbl in Updatepanel

Tags: c#, checkbox, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

Situation:
Checkbox inside a updatepanel
multiline textbox inside a different updatepanel.
if the user checks the checkbox, the multiline text box gets a name... this works fine.

HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTraveling" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional"   ChildrenAsTriggers="False">   
    <ContentTemplate>                        
       <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRUTraveler" runat="server" Text="I am a Traveler" AutoPostBack="True" 
     oncheckedchanged="cbRUTraveler_CheckedChanged1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<td>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTravelers" runat="server" ondatabinding="cbRUTraveler_CheckedChanged1"
     UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTravelers" 
      Class="textwidth"   runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
      placeholder="FName LName, FName  LName" required="required">
   </asp:TextBox>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
       ControlID="cbRUTraveler" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
  </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
C#:

protected void cbRUTraveler_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbTravelers.Text = 
   RequesterBPL.RequesterTraveling(cbRUTraveler.Checked, tbTravelers.Text);
   going = cbRUTraveler.Checked;
}
```

I also have 2 other updatepanels on the same page... a dropdown list in one updatepanel and a label in another updatepanel.  When a user selects a value in the dropdown list... it's suppose to trigger a name placement in the label.

HTML:

```
 <td>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upManager" runat="server" 
        ondatabinding="ddlTeam_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTeam" 
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />                                         
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblManager" runat="server" >  </asp:Label>                                    
          </ContentTemplate>                                  
    </asp:UpdatePanel>                            
 </td>
```

C#:

```
 protected void ddlTeam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //upManager.Update(); 
     lblManager.Text = 
     ManagerBPL.ReturnManagerName(ddlTeam.SelectedIndex);
 }
```

However, when a user makes a selection in the dropdown, nothing happens.
until the user checks the checkbox which has nothing to do with the label and the dropdown.  Once the user checks (or unchecks) the checkbox... the label gets populated with the selection from the dropdown.

All controls are in a table for structure.  I have the scriptmanager in place.

From what I've been reading on the net this maybe a bug... If not a bug does anyone see where I may be going wrong...?

Thanks

Comment: please fix the rest of this messy formatting I fixed the first part for you it's really hard to read messed up formatting when it's broken up in such a way that you pasted your code in the editor...

Comment: I understand... I was trying to make format it correctly but must have missed something.  I can no longer make edits...  Thanks

Comment: have you actually stepped thru the code.. it would actually be more beneficial to do that and only post code that is relevant to the actual line(s) of code in question where you are not seeing expected results.. also if you are expecting something to happen on the dropdown..make sure you have the `AutoPostBack` property set = to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Honestly you could do this all Client-Side. A simple example:

```
$(function () {
     $('#<%= drpContent.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
          var content = $('#<%= drpContent.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
          $('#lblContent').text(content);
     }     
});
```

I've provided the initial example with the `value` declared.  The second example is with a `text` representation.

```
$(function () {
     $('#<%= drpContent.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
          var content = $('#<%= drpContent.ClientID %> option:selected').text();
          $('#lblContent').text(content);
     }     
});
```

An example with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc9rg5qg/).  The example though is simple, is far easier then dealing with an *Update Panel*.  That particular control can be a nightmare to deal with, it can be quite painful.  Though you asked about the *server* issue, this option is more viable and more common.

Update Panel (Drawback):

- Creates pandomonium between Client / Server Side Events.
- Stores your entire page in memory, then recreates (Performance Heavy)
- Often breaks Page-State quickly in the *Asp.Net Page Life Cycle*.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I just figured out the issue with the Team dropdown and the manager label... rather let me say... I just got it to work.  I placed an AutoPostBack="true" on the "lblManager" label (not lblManagers).  The tbTravelers does not have a autopostback when a user checks the checkbox.  However the lblManager needed an autopostback when someone uses the team ddl...  I'll have to chew on this one for a minute...  I had to get it to work.... messed with me all weekend